# how to make "PayPal Express Checkout " button show below "add to cart" button on the product page

Tags: express, paypal, opencart, checkout

after enable it ,and add it to "product" page,it only show on the left,top,right or bottom, 
how to make "PayPal Express Checkout " button show **below** "add to cart" button on the product page?
and always show ,not only appear after add a product and refresh.

Thanks

Comment: What is you OpenCart version?

Comment: opencart2.3.0.2 and opencart3.x

Comment: opencart 2.3.x doesn't have the same files as opencart 3.x 
OpenCart 2.3.x has .tpl files and opencart 3.x has twig, so you can't copy paste the changes.
As for the request, you need to edit the product.tpl/.twig file to do what you want. Or ask a developer to make an extension for you.

Comment: yes,I need to edit the product.tpl/.twig.I would like to have a try by myself.thanks all the same

Answer (score 1):

I figure out the solution below
1)go to backend -extension-payment- paypal express checkout ,install,set,enable.

2)go to extension- module-paypal express checkout button,enable

3)add the following code where you would like to show  at product.tpl(if opencart 3,at product.twig)

```
<a href="index.php?route=extension/payment/pp_express/express" title="PayPal Express Checkout" style="text-decoration:none;" class="pp-express-button">
```

PayPal Express Checkout